# libGDX: How can I load TextureRegion vertecies into shader (GPU) to apply some effect on it?

Tags: java, opengl, opengl-es, libgdx

I created shader file `crop.frag` to crop effect into `Texture` as circle shape:

```
#version 150

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

vec4 borderColor;
uniform vec3 outlineColor;
uniform float outlineAlpha;
uniform float offset;
uniform float outerRadius;
uniform float innerRadius;
uniform float intensity;
uniform float brightness;

void main() {
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord0) * v_color;

    borderColor = vec4(outlineColor.rgb, outlineAlpha);

    // circle crop
    vec2 relativePosition = v_texCoord0.xy - 0.5;
    float len = length(relativePosition);
    float vignette = smoothstep(outerRadius, innerRadius, len);
    color.rgba = mix(color.rgba, color.rgba * vignette, intensity);

    // make outline over circle cropped
    float vignetteOutline = smoothstep(outerRadius - offset / 100.0, innerRadius - offset / 100.0, len);
    borderColor.rgba = mix(borderColor.rgba, color.rgba * vignetteOutline, color.a * vignetteOutline);

    gl_FragColor = color * (borderColor + brightness + 0.20);
}
```

Applying this shader to `Texture` works fine. But If I apply it to single `TextureRegion` of `Texture`, the effect applied to `region.getTexture();` only.

So, I want to modify `region` vertices in shader file I think.

I'm not expert in GL Shader Language.

Comment: Your fragment shader needs to know the texture coordinate relative to the UVs of the corners. So the vertex shader would need to pass a varying vec2 for the top left corner and another for the width and height of the region as percentage of the whole texture. If you are using SpriteBatch, this means you will have to pass that data as uniforms and therefore must flush after every individual texture region. Alternatively you could use the third party FlexBatch library to add a vertex attributes with that data.

Comment: I tried more time to pass corner of region to shader but not success. Plz provide some code to achieve that passing. The FlexBatch library is useful library Thanks @Tenfour04.